# Flatten an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, flatten

In C# what is the shortest code to flatten an array?

For example, I want

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

into the array

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I am looking for the shortest way to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721360/combining-array-of-arrays-into-single-distinct-array-using-linq

Comment: While I doubt it's the most effecient wsay of doing it, I'd create an extension function to do it for me. It would recursively loop over all elements and elements contained within elements and add them to a List<T>. Then, it would return List.ToArray()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq

Comment: @Marko Is there a shorter way?

Comment: @Naman That's as short as it gets.

Comment: It's a one liner how short do you want it?

Comment: Is it two dimensional array or Jagged array? if it is two(or multi) dimensional array it is already flattened.

Comment: What? A single-liner _isn't_ short enough for you?... You need to get your priorities straight.

Comment: Try this solution: https://gist.github.com/cirocorvino/3b387317be58b2b411b41ca039deed3e

Answer (score 41):

Maybe I'm reading "shortest code" the wrong way, but I would propose using LINQ `SelectMany` and `Distinct`:

```
var values = new[]
{
    new[] { 1, 2 },
    new[] { 2, 3 },
    new[] { 4, 5 },
};

var flattenedUniqueValues = values.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting a staggered array to a 1-dimensional array is simple and can be done in `O(n)` time and `n` space  (where `n` is the sum of 2nd-dimension array lengths), however in your example you seem to remove duplicate values - that is not flattening an array, but it can still be done in `O(n)` time but will require `O(2n)` space because you need a hashtable for `O(1)` duplicate value lookups.

A possible problem exists in knowing in advance how many elements will exist in the final array. A straightforward solution is to append to a `List<T>` and calling `.ToArray()` at the end, but that will result in `O(2n)` time and `O(3n)` space (but potentially more owing to `List<T>` internal reallocations):

```
Int32[][] jagged = ...
HashSet<Int32> seen = new HashSet<Int32>();
List<Int32> ret = new List<Int32>();

for(int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++) {
        Int32 val = jagged[i][j];
        if( !seen.Contains( val ) ) {
            ret.Add( val );
            seen.Add( val );
        }
    }
}

return ret.ToArray(); // This takes O(n) time and will allocate O(n) additional space.
```

Another solution exists by doing 2 passes yourself: the first to determine the size of the output, then the second pass to generate it - which will result in less copying: exactly `O(2n)` time and exactly `O(2n)` space:

```
Int32[][] jagged = ...
HashSet<Int32> seen = new HashSet<Int32>();

// Pass 1
for(int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++) {
        Int32 val = jagged[i][j];
        seen.Add( val ); // HashSet.Add is safe/idempotent
    }
}

Int32[] ret = new Int32[ seen.Count ];

// Pass 2
seen.Clear();

Int32 retIdx = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++) {
        Int32 val = jagged[i][j];
        if( !seen.Contains( val ) ) {
            ret[++retIdx] = val;
            seen.Add( val );
        }
    }
}

return ret;
```