# csvHelper string[][] to string[]

Tags: c#, string, csv, csvhelper

I have some data in csv like

```
string[][] items = new string[][] {
  new string[] { "dog", "3" },
  new string[] { "cat", "2" },
  new string[] { "bird", "1" }
};
```

now  I want to convert the input into properly formatted CSV lines and return them  - expected output:

```
string[] csvLines = {"\"dog\";\"3\"", "\"cat\";\"2\"", "\"bird\";\"1\""};
```

or file:

```
"dog";"3"
"cat";"2"
"bird";"1"
```

what I've tried:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCSVLines(string[][] list)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (CsvHelper.CsvWriter csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            foreach (var field in item)
            {
                csv.WriteField(field);
            }
            yield return csv.Record; //??
            csv.NextRecord();                  
        }                 
    }
}
```

Note: I can't just use `string.Join()` because the fields could contain `"`, delimiter `;` or linebreaks.

Comment: What does that have to do with CsvHelper? A simple `Select` and `String.Format` will produce the output

Comment: You want the output to contain the escaped double quotes?

Comment: Your items array is clear ?

Comment: Why not just write `list.Select(pair=>String.Format("\"{0}\";\"{1}\"",pair[0],pair[1])).ToArray()` ?

Comment: @Amy yes I've update the question

Comment: @Toshi you haven't explained why you want to use CsvHelper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining array of arrays into single, distinct array using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721360/combining-array-of-arrays-into-single-distinct-array-using-linq)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your approach fails in case of `"do"g"`

Comment: @Toshi what `"do"g"` ? It will work just fine. If a quote is missing, add it. There's nothing related to CSVs here. If you want to transform one array to another, use LINQ

Comment: The expected output looks very different from the CSV format.  It's unclear how or why CSV is even being considered.

Comment: @Toshi you'll have to explain what you're trying to do otherwise this question will be closed as unclear. I suspect you want to convert the input into properly formatted CSV lines and return them. That's not what the question asks though, the "desired output" has little to do with CSV lines

Comment: @Toshi what are you actually trying to do? The CSV contents are stored in the MemoryStream object. You could return that as one string. You could use a `StringWriter` instead of a `StreamWriter` though and get the final string directly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't Need one string, I need the single records

Comment: @Toshi update your question and explain what you actually want then - generate CSV lines from the inner arrays. The example used right now only serves to confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wrap items in quotations (with escapement: `"ab\"c"` should be `"\"ab\"\"c\""`) and `Join` them with `;` you don't need `CsvHelper` but a simple *Linq*

```
  string[][] items = new string[][] {
    new string[] { "dog", "3" },
    new string[] { "cat", "2" },
    new string[] { "bird", "1" },
    new string[] { "e\"sc", "4" } // escapment demo
  };

  string[] result = items
    .Select(line => string.Join(";", 
       line.Select(item => "\"" + item.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"")))
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
"dog";"3"
"cat";"2"
"bird";"1"
"e""sc";"4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that @Dmitry Bychenko's answer is more straight forward, but if you did want to use CsvHelper it is possible.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCSVLines(string[][] list)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (CsvHelper.CsvWriter csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

        foreach (var items in list)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                csv.WriteField(item);
            }                    
            csv.NextRecord();

            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            yield return reader.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd('\n');

            stream.Position = 0;
        }   
    }
}
```